# Python Get Redirect URL with Javascript

Tags: python, url, redirect

I am trying to get the redirected URL which has JavaScript action while redirecting to the target site

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
values = {'name' : 'DealsIndex',  'location' : 'South Bay',  'language' : 'Perl' }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request("http://www.techbargains.com/jump.cfm?clkSubId=A0AC1A00319410C5900&afsrc=1&id=6860", data, headers)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
urlapp = res.geturl()
print urlapp
```

**Actual Output:**

```
http://www.techbargains.com/jump.cfm?clkSubId=A0AC1A00319410C5900&afsrc=1&id=6860
```

**Expected Output**

```
http://shop.panasonic.com/?cm_MMC=AffiliateBanner-_-SeriouslyCool-_-88x31-_-041911
```

I tried using mechanize as well but I am not able to get to the target site.

Answer (score 0):

That redirect is done through javascript, which means you will need to use a browser that supports it. Mechanize is not one of such browsers.

Here a a couple of good ones

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) - automate actual browsers with languages (including python)
- [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) - a headless webkit browser

Comment: Can I get the target URL without a browser action ?

Comment: Not in a reliable way. you'll want to use the proper tool for the job.